# Micromax E483 calls are not establishing until mobile is restarted

Tags: calls, 4g

Recently I bought Micromax E483, it was working very nice but recently i am unable to make any call. Even after rebooting the mobile, calls are going only once or twice.

Comment: Which Service Provider are you using?

Comment: Check your Access Points settings for that service provider, Or any activation process/ recharge. Also, check your network coverage.